# Holomorphic function defined on the annulus that is zero on one of the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Assume that $f$ is holomorphic on the annulus $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon 0 < r < |z-a| < R\}$ and continuous on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon 0 < r \leq |z-a| \leq R\}$. If $f(z) = 0$ at $|z - a| = R$, prove that $f(z) \equiv 0$ in $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon 0 < r < |z-a| < R\}$.

My attempt: I have consider using maximum modulus principle, however the hypothesis is sufficient for a direct application. I have consider using Riemann mapping theorem to map the annulus to the unit disk, however the annulus is not simply connected. Is there any other way to approach this question?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You can apply [Schwarz's reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) to extend it analytically outside of the larger radius. Then that analytic function will be zero in a set that accumulates in the interior where it is analytic and thus it is zero.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The condition is being $0$ on all of $|z-a|=R$

Comment: @NDB The Schwarz's reflection principle I learned involves a symmetric domain with respect to the real-axis where the function is real-valued on the real-axis. How do you apply the Schwarz's reflection principle?

Comment: Circles and lines are the same thing. You can use a Moebius transformation to turn one into another. If Schwarz's is stated for the real line, extending the function using reflections, then the statement for a circle is the same but using inversion with respect to the circle.

Comment: @NDB ok I see it now! thank you for the hints

Comment: I added a proof to the duplicate link that does not involve analytic continuation